# Error message: No module named 'cloudant'

Tags: python, cloudant

I am trying to teach myself developing flask applications on IBM cloud. I am trying to follow the following tutorial:
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-foundry?topic=cloud-foundry-getting-started-python#getting_started

At some, I am giving the command: python .hello.py and I get the following error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "hello.py", line 1, in 
from cloudant import Cloudant
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cloudant'

Please can you tell me what is going wrong? I installed cloudant twice now.

thanks,

Naveen

Comment: which python version are you running the code with?

Comment: "*I installed cloudant twice now.*" How did you install it? What exact command did you use? If you use `python hello.py` to run your app, then check if `python -m pip list` shows "cloudant". Generally, the same Python you use to run your apps/scripts should be the same Python you use to install things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also posted this question in the IBM community group and they came back very quickly. The tutorial is old and in the file the following should be added:

from cloudant.client import Cloudant

Closing this topic.

thanks,

Naveen